# How to run app with tidesdk on linux x64?

Tags: 64-bit, debian, tidesdk

I'd like to run HelloWorld app with tidebuilder.py like this (*TideSDK Developer* from *TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-linux-x86-64.tgz* doesn't work for me):

```
./tidebuilder.py -rv TideSDK-HelloWorld-master

> Staging HelloWorld
>    -> Copying contents from /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/TideSDK-HelloWorld-master to /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/HelloWorld
>    -> Copying installer from /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/installer to /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/HelloWorld
>    -> Copying tiboot to /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/HelloWorld
> /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/xliivdeb/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/HelloWorld/HelloWorld)
```

but it **fails**, because file is missing according to the error message.
When I check it manually, diferrent thing occures, see this:

```
$  ll /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Nov 19 00:07 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so*
```

How to fix it?

Platform:
Linux alef 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.35-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is dependency issue. Some of the TideSDK dependency packages are not available or are at older version.

This issue would be resolved by having a proper deb packaged installer. This is a new feature request and is now tracked at: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/136